# QGIS/PostGIS finding shortest route going through all the polylines at least once

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a QGIS 3.10 map with two main PostGIS 3.0 layers:

1. Zones (Polygons): the town is divided in 26 zones. Each municipal street sweeper only works inside his zone.
2. Street lines (Linestrings): These are the paths municipal street sweepers follow when moving around the town.

I would like to get for each zone  (each street sweeper), which is the most optimized path in distance (and thus in time). There are several routing alternatives and I need to get the most efficient one, the one that following it would walk the lowest distance. The only condition is that it has to walk through all the lines at least once.

I've only found algorithms for finding shortest path from point to point but nothing similar to what I want...

Is there any QGIS functionality, plugin or PostGIS query that would help me with this task?

[image]

Comment: You are looking for the "Chinese Postman" algorithm - as far as I know it is NP hard so getting the optimal solution is unlikely

Comment: @IanTurton The basic Chinese Postman algorithm can be solved in polynomial time (Granted some of the more complicated variants are NP complete, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem); it may be the Traveling Salesman Problem that you are thinking about.